# Pythonic way to generate string rotations

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider a string `'1234'`. You need a function which generates all the rotations: `'1234', '3412', '4123', '2341'`. I created a simple test suite:

```
assert rotations('123') == set(['123', '231', '312'])
assert rotations('111') == set(['111'])
assert rotations('197') == set(['197', '971', '719'])
```

What is the pythonic way to do that? I finished with code below

```
def rotations(num):
    str_num = str(num)
    result = set()
    for mid in xrange(len(str_num)):
        result.add(
            str_num[mid:] + str_num[:mid]
        )
    return result
```

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: maybe a set comprehension? `{s[mid:] + s[:mid] for mid in range(len(s))}`

Comment: What you have is Pythonic enough -- though @NiklasB.'s comment, which perhaps deserves to be an accepted answer,  is probably more so (though  replace `range` by `xrange` in Python 2)

Comment: I remember using the `itertools` package to form permutations, but I kinda like that slicing approach better.

Comment: if you want more "verbose" code: Use itertools's cycle combined with "chunking"  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks?lq=1 . Btw. your function should return a set of strings, not a set with a single list of strings if you do not care for order of the elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
s='1234'
z = {s[x:]+s[:x] for x in range(len(s))}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second example suggests that your approach isn't efficient if the number is periodic (e.g. 123123123123). As a solution -- check if a given rotation has already appeared. If so -- the sequence is periodic and you have already discovered all distinguishable rotations, so just return the result:

```
def rotations(num):
    str_num = str(num)
    result = set()
    for mid in range(len(str_num)):
        rot = str_num[mid:] + str_num[:mid]
        if rot in result:
            return result
        else:
            result.add(rot)
    return result
```

(I changed your `xrange` to `range` since I am using Python 3 -- you can of course change back).

Answer (score 2):

Although definitely not the fastest or necessarily most Pythonic answer, you could use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for this.

```
from collections import deque

def rotations(s):
    s_dq = deque(s)
    result = set()
    for _ in xrange(len(s_dq)):
        s_dq.rotate(1)
        result.add(''.join(s_dq))
    return result
```

And it passes all of your example tests:

```
def main():
    tests = ['123',
             '111',
             '197']

    desired = [set(['123', '231', '312']),
               set(['111']),
               set(['197', '971', '719'])]

    for test, result in zip(tests, desired):
        print rotations(test) == result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> True
>
> True
>
> True

I would not recommend that you use collections.deque for this particular problem, but it can be applied to more complicated versions of problems like this one. It is a very useful and, in my opinion, underused tool--that's why I included it as an answer to this question.